# Ask user to input substring and return matching names with id's from database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

My method currently selects all instructors and their id's from data base.In my `selectDBT` variable, I want to define such a way so that

```
SELECT name, id from instructor where name like substring;
```

and this `substring` should be some `'%sub%'` substring that the user can input.

```
private static void selectInstructor() throws SQLException {

        Connection dataConnection = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        String selectDBT = "SELECT name, id from instructor";

        try {
            dataConnection = getConnection();
            statement = dataConnection.createStatement();

            System.out.println(selectDBT);


            ResultSet result_set = statement.executeQuery(selectDBT);

            while (result_set.next()) {

                String ins_name = result_set.getString("name");
                String ins_id = result_set.getString("id");


                System.out.println("Instructor Name : " + ins_name);
                System.out.println("Instructor ID : " + ins_id);


            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (dataConnection != null) {
                dataConnection.close();
            }

        }

    }
```

So far I was able to let user put their user id and password to enter database using java swing interface. Now I want to make another interface where the user can input `substring` which should refer to some `%sub%` string pattern matching and my output will be names and id's that match the substring. Right now I', getting all names and id's regardless since I'm not letting user to input substring matching.Also hardcoding won't work since I want user to select dynamically.

Edit: Using prepared statement:

```
private static void selectInstructor() throws SQLException {

        Connection dataConnection = null;
        Statement statement = null;





        // String selectDBT = "SELECT name, id from instructor";

        try {
            dataConnection = getConnection();

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
         dataConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT name, id from instructor where name like ?");
         preparedStatement.setString(1, substring);


            // statement = dataConnection.createStatement();

            System.out.println(preparedStatement);


            ResultSet result_set = statement.executeQuery(preparedStatement);

            while (result_set.next()) {

                String ins_name = result_set.getString("name");
                String ins_id = result_set.getString("id");


                System.out.println("Instructor Name : " + ins_name);
                System.out.println("Instructor ID : " + ins_id);


            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (dataConnection != null) {
                dataConnection.close();
            }

        }

    }
```

However, I'm getting same output. Please note that I am very new in SQL.I treid to use prepared statement from an answer suggestion.

Comment: where is the problem, did you try to solve an error or you want to know how to implement it?

Comment: In your second attempt, you need to use `preparedStatement.executeQuery()`, not `statement.executeQuery(preparedStatement)`; that won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

There are an operator [like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) you can use it like so :

```
String selectDBT = "SELECT name, id from instructor like '" + sub + "'";
//...
```

But this can gives error syntax and the worste an SQL Injection, there are some smart users, so i suggest to use [PrepapredStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
         connection.prepareStatement("SELECT name, id from instructor where name like ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, substring);
```

this can be more elpfull and more secure.

**EDIT**

You can complete your program like this :

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
         connection.prepareStatement("SELECT name, id from instructor where name like ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, substring);

//get result from your prepapredStatement
ResultSet result_set = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (result_set.next()) {
    String ins_name = result_set.getString("name");
    String ins_id = result_set.getString("id");

    System.out.println("Instructor Name : " + ins_name);
    System.out.println("Instructor ID : " + ins_id);
}
```

Comment: Honestly I'm very new and I'm not getting what do you mean.I see you suggested to replace statement , but then you have not mentioned what are the other changes I need to make in my code because of that.

Comment: Please see my edit that I tried to do using prepared statement.However, it's giving me the same output, i.e. all names and id's and would not prompt me to enter a string to search.

Comment: Also, after doing your edit, I'm getting errors for my try catch block, saying illegal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136462/discussion-between-ycf-l-and-haga-dhorse).

Comment: `try` should end with `catch(Exception e){}` like this `try {//your code here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }` @HagaDhorse

Comment: @HagaDhorse you can learn about this here http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Try_and_Catch

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple procedure in the database;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_instructor_cursor
   (p_search_string    IN  VARCHAR2,
    p_cursor_var       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN 
  OPEN p_cursor_var FOR
  SELECT name,
         id
  FROM   instructor
  WHERE  name like '%'||p_search_string||'%';

END Get_instructor_cursor;
```

Pass in your search_string and simply go through the resulting cursor that is passed back to display your results.  has the advantage that you can re-use that search easily from anywhere.